Kubuntu blocks Internet for virtual machines
The firewall (ufw) of Kubuntu 24.04 blocks the connection of virtual machines to the Internet - when I turn off the firewall there is a connection, so sure, but there are no rules to block the output. A simple bridge is configured on the system, docker is also hooked up to it. I have tested many configurations, the only thing that works is such a rule:
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT

But, after all, it allows connection from outside, from the Internet. Rules from vnetX, the physical interface in any and every order do not work. I checked quite a few of them (GPT). Previously, virtual machines normally connected to the Internet, I did not change firewall settings, something must have changed in Ubuntu. The only significant change to the system is the installation of docker.
Another symptom (I just noticed) is the lack of connection after disconnecting and reconnecting the br0 (using the Kubuntu menu)... Something in the system
brctl show br0
bridge br0 does not exist!

The connection returns after a reset.

You need to allow access to and from the internet to br0. Then you install/configure a firewall in the virtual machine to limit that access.

I don’t think anything changed in Ubuntu. I run Arch and had the same problem with QEMU and Virt-manager. I had VMs that used to connect and then didn’t. It will be something in one of those or perhaps ufw (uncomplicated firewall) on the host.

-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT - in the /etc/ufw/before.rules file works and seems to be a safe solution, what do you think?

Sorry, that is outside my range of knowledge
